# Locating Groovy under STS on Ubuntu

Tags: grails, ubuntu, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have installed Springsource Tool Suite v2.7.2 with Groovy and Grails support on Ubuntu. This works well.

I want to use the Groovy installed with STS from the command line on Ubuntu. When I type which groovy I get nothing.

How can I find where groovy is installed so I can add to the path and set up GROOVY_HOME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking about the actual groovy installation used by STS and Eclipse.

The Groovy installation used by STS is located in `/path/to/sts-2.7.2/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy_1.8.2.XXXX/lib/groovy-all-1.8.2.jar`.

`XXXX` is the version of the groovy plugin currently installed. There is also a 1.7.10 version of the plugin that you could use. Just be warned that the `XXXX` will change whenever you update your Groovy-Eclipse.

You must also be the same pPaul who asked this: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?115317-Using-Groovy-installed-with-STS  So, apologies in the delay for the response.

Answer (score 3):

I found the home for my `groovy` and `grails` executables by doing this:

```
$ which groovy
/usr/bin/groovy
$ file /usr/bin/groovy
/usr/bin/groovy: symbolic link to '../share/groovy/bin/groovy'

$ which grails
/usr/bin/grails
$ file /usr/bin/grails
/usr/bin/grails: symbolic link to '/etc/alternatives/grails'
$ file /etc/alternatives/grails
/etc/alternatives/grails: symbolic link to '/usr/share/grails/1.3.7/bin/grails'
```

So, on my Ubuntu installation, `GROOVY_HOME` should be `/usr/share/groovy/`, while `GRAILS_HOME` should be `/usr/share/grails/1.3.7/`

This was a little round-about, especially since `grails` happened to point to a link under `/etc/alternatives/`.  Maybe someone has a better way!